# $\sup B_{1 + t} - B_1$ is independent of $B_1$ for $B$ a brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

Is $\sup_{t \ge 0} B_{1 + t} - B_1$ is independent of $B_1$ for $B$ being a brownian motion? For all $t$ $B_{1+t} - B_1$ is independent of $B_1$ but this isn't enough.

I also can't use that $\sup_{t \ge 0} B_{1 + t} - B_1$ is $\infty$ a.s., because we are using the independence to prove this result.

Comment: "For all $t$ $B_{1+t} - B_1$ is independent of $B_1$ but ... this isn't enough." Indeed, but here, the whole process $(B_{1+t} - B_1)_{t>0}$ is independent of $B_1$, and *that* is enough to conclude that $\sup_{t \ge 0} B_{1 + t} - B_1$ is independent of $B_1$.

Comment: but what does "the whole processs is independent" mean?

Comment: Wow. What is your definition of Brownian motion, already?

Comment: @Did Independent increments $(B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})_{i=2,...n}$, the increments $(B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})$ are normal distributed with expected value 0 and variance $t_i - t_{i-1}$ and it has a.s. continious paths. I only heard of pairwise and mutually independence. I never heard of "a whole process independence", that is why I don't get what you formally mean by saying that. You obviously don't mean pairwise independence of $B_{1+t} - B_1$ and $B_1$ because that is what my last question was about. But $(B_{1+t} - B_1)_{t \ge 0}$ also aren't mutually independent. That is why I asked

Comment: "Independent increments $(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})_{2\leqslant i\leqslant n}$" refers to global independence, not pairwise independence. In particular, choosing $t_1=0$ and $t_2=1$, one gets that the random variable $B_1=B_1-B_0$ and the random family $(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})_{3\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ are independent. Since this holds for every $n$ and every $t_i>1$, $i\geqslant3$, and since the paths of Brownian motion are almost surely continuous, $B_1$ is indeed independent of the sigma algebra $\sigma(B_s-B_1;s>1)$, a fact which implies the result you are interested in.

Comment: @Did can you maybe give me a hint or tell me where to read up on that (how the desired result is implied. I get that with that result we are finished)? I am now searching through the internet and I see that we missed a lot of important and nice properties of the BM in lecture as it seems

Comment: Sorry but if you are given that $B_1$ is independent of the sigma-algebra $\mathcal G_1=\sigma(B_s-B_1;s>1)$, you cannot deduce that $B_1$ and $M_1=\sup\limits_{s>1}B_s-B_1$ are independent?

Comment: @Did No, the question still is why $B_1$ is independent of $G_1$. Because that isn't directly part of the definition of brownian motion as I know it. You said it follows from the random familiy $(B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})_{3 \le i \le n}$ being independent of $B_1$ and the brownian motion being a.s. continuous. This is where you lose me

Comment: Can you show that $B_1$ is independent of $(B_s-B_1)_{s\in S}$ for every finite $S\subset(1,+\infty)$? If you can, what is missing to deduce that $B_1$ is independent of $G_1$?

Comment: @Did, I got it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: OK. Where did you use the almost sure continuity of the Brownian paths?

Comment: @Did Nowhere, did I need it?: $G_{t_1, .. t_n} = \sigma(B_{t_i} - B_1)_{i=1,...n} = \sigma(B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})_{i=1,...n}, t_0 = 1$ which is independent of $\sigma(B_1)$ because $B$ is a brownian motion. Also $G_{t_1}, ..., G_{t_n}$ are stable under intersection and generate $G_1$. Thus $G_1$ and $B_1$ are independent. Did I miss something?

Comment: I somehow can't edit the upper comment anymore. I meant that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}, t_1, ..., t_n > 1}G_{t_1, ..., t_n}$ is stable under intersection and generates $G_1$

Comment: @Did Where do I need the a.s. continuity of the Brownian paths?